# Buildozer trys to compile a simple "hello world" kivy project but throws an error

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, kivy, buildozer

On terminal I'm typing this:

```
$ buildozer android debug deploy
```

Traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 9, in <module>  
    load_entry_point('buildozer==0.30', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main  
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 987, in run_command  
    self.target.run_commands(args)  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 85, in run_commands  
    func(args)  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 97, in cmd_debug  
    self.buildozer.build()  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 195, in build  
    self.build_application()  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 689, in build_application  
    self._copy_application_sources()  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 774, in _copy_application_sources  
    copyfile(sfn, rfn)  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile  
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
```

I get this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 102] Operation not supported on socket: '/Users/myImac/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/App Shim Socket'
```

I'm on Imac "El Capitan" Python 2.7/Kivy 1.9/ Cython 21.1.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and I found out it was my mistake.

I did not execute *buildozer* in the proper folder containing the `.spec` file. Check if that works for you.